# Why does this print statement screw up?

Tags: c, dirent.h

`printf("%s\n", (char*)ent->d_name);` is giving me undefined behavior. I'm just getting bizarre symbols in the output, sometimes followed by random letters. `ent` is a dirent struct.

It's being declared inside a function that's getting passed to a pthread.

```
void * copyFile( void * arg ){

struct dirent *ent = (struct dirent *)arg;

printf("%s\n", (char*)ent->d_name);

}
```

And called like this:

```
int ret = pthread_create(&thread_list[i], NULL, copyFile, &ent);
```

I tried printing the name on the original `ent` in the calling function, and it worked properly. So the problem is somewhere in the transferal and reassignment/casting.

Comment: If using `readdir` to fill the struct, keep in mind that it uses static memory. In that case, you will need to copy the struct right after the function returns.

Comment: The cast to `char*` of `d_name` is unrequired.

Comment: Readdir filled the original `ent`, and it worked well. Once it was passed to the copyFile function, within that function `ent` does not work. Regardless of whether I remove the char* casting. I can't read any of its attributes. The struct has failed to pass into the function properly.

Comment: @New2This, can you post the calling code? Specifically, is `readdir()` called again after the call to `pthread_create()`?

Comment: It's in a `while((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL )` loop that creates a thread for each entry.

Comment: Note that POSIX says: _The pointer returned by `readdir()` points to data which may be overwritten by another call to `readdir()` on the same directory stream. This data is not overwritten by another call to `readdir()` on a different directory stream._  Be careful in a threaded application to ensure that the data does not change while a thread is processing it.

Answer (score 1):

The `readdir` function uses static memory to fill the `dirent` struct. That is, subsequent calls to `readdir` will probably overwrite the same area, and referring to that piece of memory at a later point results in undefined behaviour.

You need to copy the struct right after the `readdir` call and pass this copy to the thread, not the original:

```
struct dirent *dp = readdir(dirp);
struct dirent *dp_on_the_heap = malloc(sizeof(struct dirent));
memcpy(dp_on_the_heap, dp, sizeof(struct dirent));
```

Comment: +1 AFAIK, `struct dirent` contains no dynamic members so `*dp_on_the_heap = *dp;` is an alternative to `memcpy()`.

Comment: The syntax within the `copyfile` function is OK, the location of the `arg` pointer is most probably the problem.